# Equivalente do $_SERVER['LOGON_USER'] no Linux

Tags: php, apache, php-7, linux

Na empresa onde trabalho, havia um servidor PHP5 baseado no ISS, entretanto está tendo uma migração para um outro servidor Apache baseado em Debian com PHP7.0.

Habilitei os erros do novo servidor, e vejo que estou tendo problemas `$_SERVER[LOGON_USER]`.

No antigo servidor, essa variável que utilizava para pegar as informações de login do usuário windows. Agora que migraram de servidor, consultando o resultado do `phpinfo()`, vi que essa variável não existe no novo servidor.

Existe outra forma de se obter essa informação com alguma outra variável global?

Comment: Já espiou todas as variáveis de ambiente no phpinfo com cuidado para ver se alguma serve? E faz alguma diferença do usuário do servidor na sua aplicação? (não tem nenhum login que possa ser usado em vez disso?)

Comment: Infelizmente preciso validar o usuário com a informação da conta logada na estação de trabalho para ver os níveis de acesso. As informações de acesso ficam em uma base própria, mas não posso pedir uma outra forma de acesso aos portais além do login na maquina.